# collectd: ping plugin fail randomly on medium/high number of hosts

Tags: centos6, collectd

I am trying to use collectd to monitor ping time and interface traffic of upwards of a 150 hosts, using the snmp and ping plugins (nodes are mostly routers). The servers reads stats (ping/snmp) and writes them to disk via the rrdtool plugin. All is fine with few hosts - however when I put in a hundred of them, many of the graphs - especially the ping time ones  - become fragmented showing only a fraction of the expected values or nothing at all. The logs (at debug level) show oodles of errors like:

```
rrdtool plugin: rrd_update_r (...) failed: ...  illegal attempt to update using time 1393957157 when last update time is 1393957286 (minimum one second step)
```

The same sites ping all right from the CLI. and do report some snmp data (though not all, and not reliably).

The FAQs on collectd's site mention client/server time differences or multiple plugin being loaded - both ruled out in this case. Running collectd 5.4.1  On CentOS6. I have tried to jack up red/write threads with no joy.

**EDIT**: I have since tried to activate the write-graphite plugin, and I have exactly the same faulty graphics in both rrd and graphite. So the problem appears to lie specifically with the ping plugin (and not, say, with disk I/O or the write backend).

**EDIT2**: The failing hosts have (mostly) **NaNs** added to the rrd/graphite/cvs files.

**EDIT3**: After much trial and error I found that failures begin when trying to ping upwards of 59 hosts, at which point the collectd process has about 63 sockets open. So it seems someone could have a problem with more than that amount of sockets. It does not appear to be a hard limit, however, because, configuring 116 hosts in the plugin, I can see collectd opening 118 sockets. So it could be a per thread thing or something within liboping  (1.5.1)

Comment: We got the same problem here with that plugin, as we need to monitor more than 600 servers. 
Have you found some clue ?

Comment: Nope. Asked on the collectd devlist & have bee ignored - that appears to be the norm on thath list, every question I've ever asked was...maybe it's just me. I turned to smokeping for my graphs.

Comment: We're dumping the native ping plugin and writing a custom one with the fping package which looks promising.